# Angular-2 Getting [Object Object] from @input parameter

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to transfer an object to a component using @input parameter .

**Home.html**

```
                <ion-row>
                    <ion-col *ngFor="let dc of devices">
                      <device  deviceObject="{{dc}}"></device>
                    </ion-col>
                </ion-row>
```

**Device Component html**

I want to display a property from the object in the component.

```
<div>   <label>{{dc.name}}</label> </div>
```

**Device.ts**

Declared the input deviceObject

**`@Input('deviceObject') deviceObject: Object;`**

I want to print a property but i am getting **undefined**

if i print the object **deviceObject** , i am getting **[Object object]**

Comment: are you missing square brackets around input property `[deviceObject]`?

Comment: @MadhuRanjan do you mean it in the home.html ?                              <device [ deviceObject]="{{dc}}"></device>

Comment: like this, <device [deviceObject]="dc"></device>

Comment: Thanks @MadhuRanjan . It is working. What was the problem here?

Comment: syntax was not correct [See cheatsheet!!](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cheatsheet.html)